# SQL Multiple Conditions in max statement not working

Tags: sql, max, conditional-statements, sql-server-2016-express

I am attempting to filter my table and get the item that sold for the most amount of money. In order to do this I am using "AuctionOpen" to determine whether or not the auction is still open. The auction cannot be open and have the item been sold (later I will use this for the most expensive item available).

I am able to use the AND operator to compare AuctionOpen by using the following:

```
select s.*
from auctionsite.dbo.Auction s
where s.HighestBid = (select max(s2.HighestBid) from auctionsite.dbo.Auction 
   s2) and s.AuctionOpen = 0;
```

When I set this equal to zero I get results, but when I set it equal to 1, it only returns the column titles even though there are  values set to 1 in the table.

Results when compared to 0:

[image: table]

Results when compared to 1:

[image: other table]

Comment: *The auction cannot be open and have the item been sold* so when AuctionOpen=0 this means that the auction is not open and the item has been sold and you get results. When AuctionOpen=1 the auction is still open and the item has not been sold and you don;t get results. So what is the problem?

Comment: @forpas Later on I will be using this same operation to get the highest priced item that is still available.

Comment: The sample data you posted are not indicative of the problem you say you have. So what should we do? Speculate?

Comment: Forpas.... the pictures I posted show the result of the query. Not really sure what you want here, bud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the highest bid is on a record where `AuctionOpen <> 1`.

I recommend using `order by` and `fetch` (or the equivalent in your database):

```
select s.*
from auctionsite.dbo.Auction s
where s.AuctionOpen = 0
order by s.HIghestBid desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

In SQL Server, use either `select top (1)` or `offset 0 rows fetch first 1 row only`.

Comment: This worked when changed to SQL Server syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the Count aggregate function

here, try this:

```
    **Select count(Item_name) As
```

[Item with the highest money] 
from table_name
Group by Item_name DSEC;**

You can check my page here[SQL/MySQL tips](https://fawdagroup.com/how-to-connect-to-database-in-phpmyadmin-using-xampp/16/12/2019/217/) for some SQL/MySQL lessons